# Using custom effort with Azure DevOps Server

Tags: azure-devops, agile, scrum, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-server

Everyone!
I'm current working on a company that just started to use Azure DevOps Server.

We're used to classify our work items using S for Small, M for Medium and L for Large. As an internal convention, the proportion between them is:

1 Medium = 2 Small.

1 Large = 4 Small.

So, to keep using this, we created a new field on our work items to fill the estimated size for each work item.

It was all good since then, but now we're starting to get our development metrics from Azure DevOps using queries. On the queries results, I didn't find a way to convert the size (S, M or L) into a numeric value to display on charts.

What I need is, for example, create a burndown chart considering the amount of 'S' work, following the proportion that I've mentioned above.

Anyone can suggest a way to solve my problem without changing our estimation pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> On the queries results, I didn't find a way to convert the size (S, M or L) into a numeric value to display on charts.

We do not have any built-in feature about this.

For create a burndown chart, you need to use Remaining work/Story points on tasks (and bugs if they're managed with tasks) to populate burndown data. Additionally, the dates on those work items matter. To calculate burndown we're using an "as of" query that asks what the work item looked like on a specific day. For example, we're asking what the remaining work of tasks of User Story.

More details please take a look at our official doc here-- [Configure and monitor sprint burndown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/dashboards/configure-sprint-burndown?view=azure-devops&tabs=remaining-work%2Cmay)

As a workaround in your scenario, you could export your work items to Excel.  Then use Excel report to achieve what you need.